# unable to record teamcenter application using loadrunner 12.50.receiving JVM Terminated.exit code =2

Tags: loadrunner

I am not able to record team center application(desktop based application) using Loadrunner 12.50. Getting "JVM Terminated.exitcode=2". I am able to launch application manually. Not able to communicate using load runner. The server is set in a different geographic location. I have tried the below possibilities.

- Java version was set appropriately in environment variables.
- Tried removing the JDK path from system variable
- Able to ping the server from cmd
- Using the recommended java version

Machine configuration:
Windows 7,64 bit, 4 GB RAM,Loadrunner 12.50, Teamcenter 11.02, JAVA 1.8
Protocol used: Web(http/html)
Invoke method: Using command prompt

Answer (score 0):

I am going to ask a clarifying se3t of questions based upon application architecture:

1. You are using Web as the protocol you are recording from communication from the Java-based thick client to the next upstream architectural component.  What has informed this decision to use this protocol?  Setup Guides? Wireshark capture?  Winsock Capture with buffer analysis? An assumption that every application is a web/http application?
2. VUGEN is a 32 bit application and you appear to be working with a 64 bit JVM (assumption)?  Have you considered a 32 bit JVM to be invoked from a 32 bit application?
3. You make no note of how you are recording.  LoadRunner has several options.  You have the default sockets based recorder, a proxy recorder, and even using the proxy recorder on a separate host with the HTTP proxy on the application host redirected to the second host for capture.  Have you tried all of these methods and which one(s) are working/not working for you?
4. Has this ever worked for anyone in your organization or are you the first to experiment with getting this to work?  What analogs can you draw from your experience with similar architectures (JVM thick client) for insight?

Answer (score 0):

TeamCenter 12.2
C:\Siemens\Teamcenter12\4TierClient\portal\plugins\configuration_12000.2.0
client_specific.properties

useAppLauncher=false
preferred4TierServerUrlForMSOfficeClient=http://localhost:7001/tc

PortalViewer_Cache=C:/Siemens/Teamcenter12/4TierClient/portal/temp
portalCommunicationTransport=tccs

TeamCenter 12.2 by Loadruner webhttp+winsocet don't recording!